# List separated by semicolons, ending with a period

Tags: xstring, parsing

I am using a university-developed document class for my thesis. This class has the command `\keywords` which takes a list of `\key` commands and this is printed out as a keyword list after the abstract. These commands are masked in portuguese into `\chaves` and `\chave`, respectively.

An example input is:

```
\chaves{%
  \chave{A}%
  \chave{B}%
  \chave{C}%
  \chave{D}%
}
```

Unfortunately, this list is currently printed entirely separated by periods, which is different than the university's standards (even though its university-developed, go figure), so I'm having to modify the document class in order to make it work.

I went into the document class and found this:

```
\newcommand{\key}[1]{}
\newcommand{\puc@keywords}{}
\newcommand{\keywords}[1]{\renewcommand{\puc@keywords}{#1}}
\newcommand{\chave}[1]{\key{#1}}
\newcommand{\chaves}[1]{\keywords{#1}}
% ...
\renewcommand{\key}[1]{##1.\hspace{3mm} }%
\indent \puc@keywords%
```

Modifying `\renewcommand{\key}` into `##1;\hspace{3mm}`, I got the list separated by semicolons, which is correct. Only the last item on the list is unfortunately also printed with a semicolon, where it should be a period.

I have tried using the `xstring` package to delete the last semicolon and print a period, but I've been unsuccessful. Modifying the snippet above, and replacing the last line with `\indent \StrGobbleRight{\puc@keywords}{2}%`, I get the error `Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.` I've looked this error up but haven't figured it out. I've tried placing `\protect` around the `\chave` calls to no avail. I've tried putting `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` around the call, which also didn't help. I've tried using `\StrExpand` in order to expand the call, but that didn't work either. I was able to get `\StrExpand` itself to work with `\StrExpand[1]{\puc@keywords}{\test}`, after which printing `\test` works. However, if I then try `\StrGobbleRight{\test}{2}`, I get `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].`

I think my mistake is mostly conceptual, but in case its of any use, below follows an MWE, but the problem is actually dealing with a (1100+ line) class file which can be found [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3087637/ThesisPKKN3.cls). The relevant code is around line 608.

```
\documentclass[dissertacao,brazil]{ThesisPKKN3}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\autor{A}
\autorR{A}
\orientador{A}
\orientadorR{A}
\titulo{A}
\dia{20} \mes{Março} \ano{2015}
\cidade{Rio de Janeiro}
\CDD{A}
\departamento{A}
\programa{A}
\centro{A}
\universidade{Pontifícia Universidade Católica do Rio de Janeiro}
\uni{PUC-Rio}
\banca{
  \membrodabanca{A}{PUC-Rio}
  \membrodabanca{A}{USP}
  \membrodabanca{A}{PUC-Rio}
  \coordenador{A}
}
\curriculo{%
A}
\agradecimentos{%
A
}
\chaves{%
  \chave{A}%
  \chave{A}%
  \chave{A}%
  \chave{A}%
}
\resumo{
A
}
\chavesuk{
  \chave{A}%
  \chave{A}%
  \chave{A}%
  \chave{A}%
}
\titulouk{A}
\resumouk{%
A
}
\modotabelas{figtab} % nada, fig, tab ou figtab
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introdução}
    \section{Objetivos}
\chapter{Protensão}
    \section{Introdução}
\chapter{Implementação do programa}
    \section{Introdução}
\chapter{Passo-a-passo do programa com exemplo}
\chapter{Demais exemplos}
    \section{Viaduto da Guarita - Pista Norte}
\chapter{Conclusões}
    \section{Sugestões para trabalhos futuros}
\chapter{Dados dos exemplos}
    \section{Viaduto de acesso a Santa Isabel}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:**

After @cfr's comment and answer, I noticed I didn't mention the fact that the keywords are repeated elsewhere, and in that circumstance the keywords are separated by periods (I hate my university's format), so is there a way of doing this which allows for separator-flexibility?

Comment: Can you create a minimal example we can compile? Why the complexity? Why not just `\chaves{keyword,keyword, keyword...}`? `xpunctuate` might help.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention this, but unfortunately the `\chaves` are used elsewhere, and there they are separated by periods, not semicolons. So storing the individual keys and modifying the separator locally becomes somewhat necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are rewriting this bit anyway, why not make it easier and set things up so you can just enter your keywords as a comma-separated list? If a keyword includes a comma, just surround it with curly brackets.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\clist_new:N \l_wasabi_chaves_clist
\NewDocumentCommand\chaves { m }
{
  \clist_set:Nn \l_wasabi_chaves_clist { #1 }
}
\NewDocumentCommand \puc@keywords {}
{
  \clist_use:Nnnn \l_wasabi_chaves_clist { ;~ }{ ;~ }{ ;~ }.
}
\let\test\puc@keywords
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
  \chaves{abc, def, 5 and three-quarters, {red, white and blue}, Tall interventions, little green men, large purple women, Sam's childrens' sea-shells}
  \test
\end{document}
```

[image: keywords]

## EDIT

In response to the updated question and information, the easiest way might be to create `\puc@keywords[]` to take an optional argument. I've set it up to consist of a semicolon and a space by default, but as the following shows, you can equally use `\puc@keywords[.\hspace{3mm}]` in the other position where this is required.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\clist_new:N \l_wasabi_chaves_clist
\NewDocumentCommand\chaves { m }
{
  \clist_set:Nn \l_wasabi_chaves_clist { #1 }
}
\NewDocumentCommand \puc@keywords { O {;} }
{
  \clist_use:Nnnn \l_wasabi_chaves_clist { #1~ }{ #1~ }{ #1~ }.
}
\def\test{
  \puc@keywords\par
  \puc@keywords[.\hspace{3mm}]
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
  \chaves{abc, def, 5 and three-quarters, {red, white and blue}, Tall interventions, little green men, large purple women, Sam's childrens' sea-shells}
  \test
\end{document}
```

[image: two ways to punctuate keywords]

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment on the OP, something I forgot to mention (I'll edit the OP after writing this) is that the keywords are repeated elsewhere, and in that case they are separated with periods. Can this method deal with changing the separator?

Comment: @Wasabi Is there another command you are using for that case? Or how does it work exactly? Yes, you can redefine the separator: it is just a question of how best to do that to work with the code you've got.

Comment: The same exact code is used in both places. It's just that in that other position, `\renewcommand{\key}[1]{##1.\hspace{3mm} }%` (which is what's currently in both places) is precisely what is needed.

Comment: @Wasabi See edit. I'd set this up so that you can write `\puc@keywords` in one place and `\puc@keywords[.\hspace{3mm}]` in the other. It still seems easier to handle this as a comma-separated list. (And surely it simplifies entry of the keywords in the document itself!)