# Automatically end list item with proper punctuation (semicolon, period)

Tags: lists, itemize, punctuation

If I have a list using `itemize`, I want to automatically end each `\item` with a semicolon (for all but the last item) or a period (for the last item).

For example:

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item One
  \item Two
  \item Three
\end{itemize}
```

Should display as

- One;
- Two;
- Three.

Is there any way to make that happen? I looked around but didn't really find anything. The closest I could find was [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257029/list-separated-by-semicolons-ending-with-a-period), but that seems to be a fancy, custom list rather than a vanilla `itemize`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure whether it is a good idea to do this, maybe you should use a different environment for that. The following patches `\item` inside every `itemize` environment to add a semicolon after the first, and the `\enditemize` macro is changed to add a dot. You can no longer nest `itemize` environments with this simple approach. All in all I think this creates more problems than it solves...

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}
  {%
    \def\itemizepunctuation{\def\itemizepunctuation{\ifhmode\unskip\fi;}}%
    \pretocmd\item{\itemizepunctuation}{}{}%
    \pretocmd\enditemize{\ifhmode\unskip\fi.}{}{}%
  }

\newenvironment{punctitemize}
  {%
    \itemize
    \def\itemizepunctuation{\def\itemizepunctuation{\ifhmode\unskip\fi;}}%
    \pretocmd\item{\itemizepunctuation}{}{}%
    \pretocmd\enditemize{\ifhmode\unskip\fi.}{}{}%
  }
  {%
    \enditemize
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item One
  \item Two
  \item Three
\end{itemize}

\begin{punctitemize}
  \item One
  \item Two
  \item Three
\end{punctitemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** added the environment approach, nesting is still not supported.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When you say use a different environment, do you mean add a new `punctuateditemize` (for example) rather than overriding the default `itemize`? If so, could you give an example of what this would look like?

Comment: @Marcel see my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I am nitpicking now, but if I have a newline in the `\item`, the semicolon / period is on its own line. I don't suppose there is any way to fix that?

Comment: Actually, it looks like that happens if there is a newline in the `itemize`.

Comment: @Marcel what do you mean with "newline"? The semicolon is added at the place where the `\item` is called, all it does beforehand is removing a space if it was preceded by one (or any other single skip). There is not much I can do additionally to that.

Comment: @Skillmon Probably Marcel is referring to a blank line between items. Try it.

Comment: @egreg oh, in the sources... Nothing I can do about that in this approach.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `xparse`, absorbing the whole contents and splitting it at `\item`; then add a semicolon (and the removed `\item`) between items.

The processing is complicated by the fact that a blank line between items would introduce a spurious paragraph before the semicolon or the final period, so we need to remove blanks and `\par` tokens at the end of each item.

Thus the sequence obtained by splitting at `\item` is mapped to “purify” it.

I added `enumitem` for maximum flexibility.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{autoitemize}{O{} +b}
 {
  \begin{itemize}[#1]
  \marcel_autoitemize:n { #2 }
  \end{itemize}
 }{}

\seq_new:N \l__marcel_autoitemize_items_seq
\seq_new:N \l__marcel_autoitemize_items_nopar_seq
\tl_new:N \l__marcel_autoitemize_item_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \marcel_autoitemize:n
 {
  % split the contents at \item; this also removes blanks at either end
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__marcel_autoitemize_items_seq { \item } { #1 }
  % remove the first (empty) item
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l__marcel_autoitemize_items_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  % we need to remove trailing \par tokens
  \seq_clear:N \l__marcel_autoitemize_items_nopar_seq
  \seq_map_function:NN \l__marcel_autoitemize_items_seq \__marcel_autoitemize_purify:n
  % start the first item
  \item
  % use the sequence, putting a semicolon and \item between items
  \seq_use:Nn \l__marcel_autoitemize_items_nopar_seq { ; \item }
  % end up with a period
  .
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__marcel_autoitemize_purify:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__marcel_autoitemize_item_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { \s* \c{par}* \Z } { } \l__marcel_autoitemize_item_tl
  \seq_put_right:NV \l__marcel_autoitemize_items_nopar_seq \l__marcel_autoitemize_item_tl
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{autoitemize}
  \item One

  \item Two
  \item Three
\end{autoitemize}

\begin{autoitemize}[label=--]
  \item One
  \item Two
  \item Three
\end{autoitemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since there is the new (2021) hook system, you are done with:

```
\AddToHook{env/itemize/end}{.}
```

Side effect: an empty space before the dot. No idea how to remove it.

For the manual see /texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/lthooks-doc.pdf , if you have a full installation of texlive.

Comment: Pointing out the manual is a big help!